# What does this mean? ✳

Tags: support

**EDIT**:

Apparently, this is a large asterisk for most users. Seems good to me. However, for me, it's a blinding luminous bright green diagonal block with a white star-like object in the middle! I'm using a Mac.

Does anybody know how to get rid of this unwelcome retina-jarring eyesore and turn it into a normal asterisk?

---

What does this new eyeball-fracking sign at the beginning of ***✳**a phrase **like this indicate**?
 **✳**I'm really **perplexed***.

I've seen them [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51686/i-would-have-liked-to-have-seen-john-before-he-left-for-canada-but-mary-didnt/51690#51690)

Is this the new form of bold or italics?

I hope not!

Comment: Eyeball-fracking!! I heart that!

Comment: Perhaps we should put information about "standard notation conventions" in one of the help pages. Or maybe a dedicated meta page like the one for [resources](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/) would be quicker and easier. There's also **?** before a text (questionable/unacceptable to some/all speakers), and **??** (*very* little endorsement). A link to a standard IPA chart wouldn't go amiss there either. Anyway, I'll probably use *this* page now to cut&paste the symbol, since I always have to go hunting for an instance! :)

Comment: Note, by the way, that some of us have taken to experimenting with various alternatives to the ordinary asterisk, because that sign interacts in unintended ways with the Markdown syntax. I for instance use this: `<sup>&lowast;</sup>`.

Comment: @StoneyB If you'd like, you can use a regular asterisk.  Just put a backslash before it: `\*`  It should show up normally, even in the middle of bold and italic text.

Comment: @snailboat 'doh!

Answer (score 1):

From context, it appears to mean "this sentence is unacceptable"—the usual convention for asterisks.

It's Unicode character U+2733, the "[Eight Spoked Asterisk](http://codepoints.net/U+2733)", a denizen of the [Dingbats](http://codepoints.net/search?blk=Dingbats) block.

On my my Mac, it shows up as a large asterisk, centered in the character block. How does it look on your computer?

Comment: It's a blinding luminous bright green diagonal block with a white star-like object in the middle! [that seems to have been specially formatted to look like that - from the cut and paste I did from the edit box ].

Comment: @Araucaria: sounds like a problem with your machine. It shows up as an italic-styled asterisk for me.

Answer (score 1):

From a [comment thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192609/usage-of-coruscating/192610#comment402041_192610) between myself and @tchrist:

> [W]hat does the asterisk denote when ELU users prefix a word with it?
>
> [I]t indicates an ungrammatical or impossible word or construction of some sort. This is the ***bogosity asterisk***, and it is not so much an ELU habit as it is one of general linguistics literature.
>
> Note however that there is another quite distinct use that linguists routinely make of “asterisk(ed) words”: a reconstructed or inputed or deduced word that the writer thinks may (or must) have existed but for which no direct written evidence actually exists, such as some hypothetical PIE word. That one is the ***hypothetical asterisk***.

Comment: Is it mean to have a bright green background?

Comment: @Araucaria I don't see a bright green background. Just a larger-than-normal asterisk (which has hints of being an "image" or emoticon rather than straight text; kinda like the way LaTEX is rendered here). Here's s [screenshot of what it looks like in the SE app running on iOS](http://imgur.com/mgSL9gw).

Comment: Well, that seems nice and clear. Don't suppose you know what I can do to get rid of the bright green box I've got on my screen?

Comment: What OS and browser are you using (with versions)? Any special fonts installed, or software (eg desktop publishing) that would install special fonts? Might be worth asking (with screenshots) over at [SU].

Comment: I'm using OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 and Firefox 35.0.1 ... Only special fonts are for IPA symbols ...

Comment: If you open the page in Safari (or Chrome or Opera if you have them), is the character still green?

Comment: Ah, no. I'll have a fiddle around with the add-ons on firefox and see what happens. Thanks :-)

Comment: When you figure out which addon is causing the trouble, it's worth posting that as an answer & accepting it, for the next guy who runs into this problem.

Comment: Weird! Now *I'm* seeing them as bright green boxes with a blinding white star, too! As a sort of emoticon? Maybe the Apple's recent expansion of its emoticon repertoire interprets what once was a simple character as an emoticon now.

Comment: It is weird isn't it? I never managed to find out what was causing that ...